# Choropleth function cant work with Geojson properly

Tags: python, geojson, folium

I have been trying to make a choropleth map with geojson and data from mssql. However, some errors keep happening.

The error is :

```
geojson_layer = folium.GeoJson(json.load(open("C:/Users/Tellus/PycharmProjects/taoyunMap/taoyuanGJ.geojson" , encoding="utf8", errors="ignore"), strict=False),

File "C:\Users\Tellus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\json\__init__.py", line 296, in load
    parse_constant=parse_constant, object_pairs_hook=object_pairs_hook, **kw)
File "C:\Users\Tellus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\json\__init__.py", line 361, in loads
    return cls(**kw).decode(s)
File "C:\Users\Tellus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
File "C:\Users\Tellus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\json\decoder.py", line 353, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)

json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting ',' delimiter: line 2 column 2 (char 48)
```

I can only guess "the line 2 column2 " refers to the geojson file "type":"FeatureCollection", but I am not sure. I have tried to fix the encoding problem, missing geometry, and so on. But can't find the way to solve the JSONDecodeError problem.

The following is part of my geojson file.

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"name": "Export_Output_2",
"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "TOWNID": "H05", "TOWNCODE": 
"68000050", "COUNTYNAME": "桃園市", "TOWNNAME": "蘆竹區", "TOWNENG": 
"Luzhu District", "COUNTYID": "H", "COUNTYCODE": "68000", "Area": 
74826480.720100001 }, "geometry": { "type": "Polygon", 
"coordinates": [ [ [ 121.263813998000046, 25.121976400000054 ], [
```

The following is part of my code.

```
taoDis = os.path.join( os.getcwd(),"taoyuanGJ.geojson")
geojson_layer = 
    folium.GeoJson(json.load(open("C:../taoyuanGJ.geojson" , 
    encoding="utf8", errors="ignore"), strict=False),
    name="geojson")

df1 =pd.DataFrame(row1, columns 
    ['DISTRICT','Frequence','Debt','H_COUNT'])


folium.Choropleth(geo_data=geojson_layer,
     name='DEBT',
     data= df1,
     columns=['DISTRICT','Debt'],
     key_on='feature.TOWNNAME',
     fill_color='YlGn',
     fill_opacity=0.5,
     line_opacity=0.9,
     legend_name='$').add_to(m)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi. Could you tell us what `line 2 column 2` refers to ? 
Also, could you add the whole stacktrace of the error ?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply, I have updated the error content.

Comment: Before anything and if you didn't do it already, I suggest you try validating your geojson using [geojsonlint](http://geojsonlint.com/) or [geojson.io](http://geojson.io)

Comment: Yes, I did validate the geojson file, and it returned there is nothing wrong. Afterwards, I decided to change another geojson file, it turned out working!!